# how to tell what is the current UIView/UIController after an iPhone app in brought back to foreground?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

After an iPhone app is put into background, then the user clicks on it again and it comes back to foreground, THEN

Question - How to tell what is the current `UIView`/`UIController` after an iPhone app in brought back to foreground?

I know that the application delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` method can be used to trap the return to foreground.  I also know that each controller could subscribe via notification centre to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

But if what I want to do is reload the UI data in the `UIView`/`UIController` that is displayed, and not carry out this same operation through all other view/controllers, how can I tell which is the one to do the `reloadData` on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using a nav controller, you can use this:

```
self.navigationController.visibleViewController
```